# Objects Data Printing

Tags: javascript, object, math

I got stuck on a question while doing JavaScript exercises. A data is given in const and we are asked to print the data to the console. But despite all my attempts, I couldn't.

Question:

> Count logged in users, count users having greater than equal to 50 points from the following object.
>
> ```
> const users = {
>   John: {
>     email: 'john@john.com',
>     skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux', 'Node.js'],
>     age: 20,
>     isLoggedIn: true,
>     points: 50
>   },
>   Thomas: {
>     email: 'thomas@thomas.com',
>     skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React'],
>     age: 20,
>     isLoggedIn: false,
>     points: 40
>   },
>   Paul: {
>     email: 'paul@paul.com',
>     skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'],
>     age: 20,
>     isLoggedIn: false,
>     points: 40
>   }
> }
> ```

I tried the for loop and the if else method, but I could not reach a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `Object.values()` and `filter()` to do it

```
let loginUserCnt = Object.values(users).filter(u => u.isLoggedIn).length
console.log(loginUserCnt)

let pointUserCnt = Object.values(users).filter(u => u.points >= 50).length
console.log(pointUserCnt)
```

```js
const users = {
  Alex: {
    email: 'alex@alex.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 30
  },
  Asab: {
    email: 'asab@asab.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Redux', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'],
    age: 25,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 50
  },
  Brook: {
    email: 'daniel@daniel.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux'],
    age: 30,
    isLoggedIn: true,
    points: 50
  },
  Daniel: {
    email: 'daniel@alex.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Python'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 40
  },
  John: {
    email: 'john@john.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux', 'Node.js'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: true,
    points: 50
  },
  Thomas: {
    email: 'thomas@thomas.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 40
  },
  Paul: {
    email: 'paul@paul.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 40
  }
}

let loginUserCnt = Object.values(users).filter(u => u.isLoggedIn).length
console.log(loginUserCnt)

let pointUserCnt = Object.values(users).filter(u => u.points >= 50).length
console.log(pointUserCnt)
```